# IcCube - How to retrieve full error messages for failed Google Analytics Api Calls

Tags: iccube

When you hit the "Refresh Datatable" Button for a misconfigured datatable inside the Google Analytics Plugin the command fails with the message:
`Failed to load columns for table 'My Table' due to following error: 'Google Analytics Error'`

This is not very descriptive.
So, how to get the fully qualified error-message which comes from the Google Analytics API?

Is there a way inside the icCube to log the error message which comes from the Google-API?
I tried to set all log-levels to `DEBUG`, but it did not help.

Alternatively, does Google log these errors, so that I can view them anywhere at the developer console?

Comment: I think you should contact the owner of your plugin.

Comment: There is catch not throwing the exception correctly, will be fixed in the next release. thanks for reporting http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-254

Answer (score 1):

It's an error on the current icCube version, will be fixed in 6.0 RC2.

[Issue 254](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-254)

Comment: Very Nice! Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the Datatable, the API-Call `analytics.data.ga.get` is triggered.

So you can simulate this call inside the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=de#p/analytics/v3/analytics.data.ga.get).

Here you just need to put in the metrics and dimensions, like you did in the IcCube IDE.
How to get the profile Id is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379602/how-to-get-google-profile-id-from-tracking-code).

After hitting the Execute-Button you can now see the full error-message.
A common error is to ask for more dimensions or metrics than allowed (max. 10 metric, 7 dimensions).

Of course it would be much more convenient, if the icCube Plugin would read the error-message and print it inside the IDE or the log...